# Javascript promise not executing in desired order

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, frisby.js

I have been trying to execute a number of tests for an API, for this example it required my account details to be updated. When I run the test the retrieveAccount call is sometimes run before my putRequest making the tests fail. What am I doing wrong?

```
var frisby = require('frisby');
var url = require('endpoints.js');
var auth = require('auth.js');
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var dbConnect = require('dbconfig.js');

var myDetails = undefined;

  var putRequest = function() {
    frisby.create('Put update contact details - required values')
      .put(url.myAccount, {
        addressLine1: 'String',
        addressTown: 'String',
        addressCounty: 'String'
      }, {json: true})
      .expectStatus(200)
      .expectHeaderContains('content-type', 'application/json')
      .auth(auth.username, auth.password)
    .toss();
  }

  var retrieveAccount = function() {
    oracledb.getConnection(
      {
        user          : dbConnect.user,
        password      : dbConnect.password,
        connectString : dbConnect.connectString
      },
      function(err, connection)
      {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return;
        }

        connection.execute(
          "SELECT addressLine1, addressTown, addressCounty "
          + "FROM accounts "
          + "WHERE account_id = 1",

          function(err, result)
          {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err.message);
              return;
            }
            myDetails = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
            myDetails = JSON.parse(myDetails);
        });
    });
  }

  var matchValues = function() {
    frisby.create('Match Database and API Values')
      .get(url.myAccount)
      .expectStatus(200)
      .expectHeaderContains('content-type', 'application/json')
      .auth(auth.username1, auth.password1)
      .afterJSON(function (body) {
        expect(body.addressLine1).toMatch(myDetails[0][0])
        expect(body.addressCounty).toMatch(myDetails[0][1])
        expect(body.addressTown).toMatch(myDetails[0][0])
      })
    .toss();
  }

  function Promise(fn) {
    var state = 'pending';
    var value;
    var deferred = null;

    function resolve(newValue) {
      value = newValue;
      state = 'resolved';

      if(deferred) {
        handle(deferred);
      }
    }

    function handle(handler) {
      if(state === 'pending') {
        deferred = handler;
        return;
      }

      if(!handler.onResolved) {
        handler.resolve(value);
        return;
      }

      var ret = handler.onResolved(value);
      handler.resolve(ret);
    }

    this.then = function(onResolved) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        handle({
          onResolved: onResolved,
          resolve: resolve
        });
      });
    };

    fn(resolve);
  }

  function sendRequest() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      var value = putRequest();
      resolve(value);
    });
  }

  function readDatabase() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      var value = retrieveAccount();
      resolve(value);
    });
  }

  function getAccount() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      var value = matchValues();
      resolve(value);
    });
  }

sendRequest()
  .then(readDatabase)
  .then(getAccount);
```

Comment: Uh, neither of your functions return any values? They're asynchronous, `var value = putRequest();` cannot work!

Comment: @Bergi I am aware they are asynchronous, I am looking to execute them in a particular order. What would you propose as a solution?

Comment: You need to give them callbacks, so that you can construct your promises properly by passing `resolve` to them.

Comment: HOLY WOW, YOU HAVE A PROMISE IMPLEMENTATION THERE? You __really__ think it's __that__ simple to create a working promise implementation and this is all promises do?

Comment: @LeeChant I'm not sure if you're sarcastic or not but there are a ton of things your implementation doesn't do right, for example if there are two handlers it'll silently drop the first one, it doesn't have the async guarantees promises have and will use race conditions, it doesn't handle rejections nor is it throw safe. If you want to learn how promises work consider reading http://modernjavascript.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/promisesa-understanding-by-doing.html

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks for the link, I shall have a read and try again. I don't post often and only do so when I can't see a solution, however bad my code maybe this is what I've understood so far

Comment: As abrasive as Bejanmin may have been, he is right. Promises are not simply beasts, and the popular libraries have grown to many hundreds of lines of code to deal with that complexity. Rolling your own implementation is a tall order, one that StackOverflow is unlikely to be able to help you complete. I recommend checking out Bluebird or Q.js

Comment: @Tyrsius I have been advised by others to use Bluebird also, thanks for the reply. I was using the Promise library before I posted this example which probably of been a better example to post in reflection

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using sequenty instead of promises to execute synchronous REST calls.

sudo npm install sequenty

```js
var sequenty = require('sequenty'); 

function f1(cb) // cb: callback by sequenty
{
  frisby.create('Match Database and API Values')
      .get(url.myAccount)
      .expectStatus(200)
      .expectHeaderContains('content-type', 'application/json')
      .auth(auth.username1, auth.password1)
      .afterJSON(function (body) {
        expect(body.addressLine1).toMatch(myDetails[0][0])
        expect(body.addressCounty).toMatch(myDetails[0][1])
        expect(body.addressTown).toMatch(myDetails[0][0])
        cb();
      })
    .toss();
}

function f2(cb)
{
  frisby.create('Put update contact details - required values')
      .put(url.myAccount, {
        addressLine1: 'String',
        addressTown: 'String',
        addressCounty: 'String'
      }, {json: true})
      .expectStatus(200)
      .expectHeaderContains('content-type', 'application/json')
      .auth(auth.username, auth.password)
    .toss();
}

sequenty.run([f1, f2]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll take a look